# How to determine the URL referrer in a development environment

Tags: angular, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, referrer

I have an Angular 8 application with a .NET Framework WebAPI backend. The client is Google Chrome version 87.0.4280.66.

The application sends an HTTP request to the backend. The backend uses HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer to read the URL of the send page.
This is done to send an email back to the user with a link to the application. This link contains the referrer.

On the Productions Server this works fine. Only on the development machine with "localhost:4200" and a different url for the backend localhost:xxxx this does not work.
On the development machine only the origin is returned with UrlReferrer.

Example:

Development
http://localhost:4200/start => http://localhost:4200

Production
http://sample.com/start => http://sample.com/start

With Firefox it works.

The assumption is that the reason is the default setting `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` in Chrome since version 85.

- Can anyone confirm this?
- What are the possibilities to configure this so that this problem does not occur anymore?